# My question disappeared just now. Is it deleted or it is on hold?

Tags: support

I didnt find a .SE about pic mcu, plus I am ban in EE.SE. So I did amiss a question here in the meta with the title alike "How to make a 3-wire SPI communication with PIC16F877A".

Was my question deleted or it is on hold?
I am not finding it anymore.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, I deleted that technical question from this Meta site.

The Meta site is the wrong place for technical questions. Even if you have a question ban on the main site, you cannot start asking technical questions on the Meta site, as they are off-topic *here*.

As I commented on that question before I deleted it from Meta (and as I see you are doing), your best plan (but not guaranteed) to remove a question ban, is to follow [this advice](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/question-bans) from the [help](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help).

Do not try to avoid the question ban in any other way. Thanks.

Comment: I was not trying to avoid. I just not paid attention that here was the meta, because I've never had used here before.

Comment: @Guilherme - "*I was not trying to avoid*" I was just giving you general advice :-)

Comment: @Guilherme - If you cannot see the PIC-related question in your account that you asked here in Meta, and if you want to copy the text from it so that you can ask that question somewhere else, then let me know and I can give you a copy of the question text.

Comment: Yes please. I need a copy so I could ask after my ban go away.

Comment: @Guilherme - I have put the original question into this chat room for you: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126311/room-for-samgibson-and-guilherme

Comment: Thank You SamGibson. I am glad for hear that.

Comment: @Guilherme - Just to be clear, please *take a copy* of your original question text from that chat room *now*, because that room is likely to disappear in the future. Don't expect that chat room to be available for very long. Thanks.

Comment: @Guilherme - As I explained in comments on the (currently deleted) technical question which you asked on Meta, I could not move it to the main site as you had an automatic question ban there. I just checked and, after the edits you have been doing, *currently* your account's question ban has been removed. Therefore you could now ask that PIC-related question there. To be honest, I don't think what you asked on Meta before was a good question e.g. the question in the *title* was different to the question in the *text*, but it's up to you. I just wanted to update you about the question ban.

Comment: So cool, I'm glad to hear it. Have a nice day, Mr. SamGibson. :-)